# Update query contain special characters

Tags: sql

Im my sql query update I have some french words to be updated but because of the `'` I got an error when I run the following query.

```
update tablename
set CLD_TEXTE = 'Le système de personnalisation a posteriori prévu à l'article 3B, Titre I, des 
conditions générales n'est pas d'application.'
where CLD_TEXTE is not null;
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Which SQL system are you using (e.g. mySQL, MS SQL Server, Oracle, something like that)? Normally you can escape such characters with a backslash or an extra quote mark e.g. `à l\'article 3B` or `à l''article 3B`. What's permitted depends on which database system you're using.

Comment: @ADyson: in (standard) SQL, single quotes are escaped by doubling them `'Arthur''s house'`

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name true. Some DBMSs also accept the backslash though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ADyson @a_horse_with_no_name is correct:

```
update tablename
set CLD_TEXTE = 'Le système de personnalisation a posteriori prévu à l''article 3B, Titre I, des 
conditions générales n''est pas d''application.'
where CLD_TEXTE is not null;
```

This should fix this for you!